# puts implementation in assembly with nasm x86-64

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, puts

I'm new to assembly and I'm trying to work on an implementation of the C function puts in assembly with nasm x86-64 on my Ubuntu.

Everything was fine until I write the tests for the function: there is a behavior that I can not reproduce:
When I send char *str = strdup(""); to my puts function (alias ft_puts), my function return an error instead of printing a newline like the original puts function.

Here is my puts implementation (ft_puts.s):

```
section .data
new_line        db      10      ; new line

section     .text
global      ft_puts
extern      strlen

ft_puts:                        ; Alias int puts(const char *s)
    call    strlen
    push    rax                 ; Number of printed chars have to be returned by ft_puts

    cmp     rax, 0
    jg      print_string        ; if length > 0, print string
    cmp     rax, 0
    jz      print_newline       ; else if length == 0 (jle or <= 0, give the same result to my problem), print new line char
    jmp     error               ; else go to error

print_string:
    mov     rsi, rdi            ; string arg for write
    mov     rdi, 1              ; file_descriptor arg for write
    mov     rdx, rax            ; length arg returned by ft_strlen for write
    mov     rax, 1              ; write
    syscall

    test    rax, rax
    jle     error               ; if write failed, go to error
    jmp     print_newline       ; else print new line char

print_newline:
    mov     rsi, new_line       ; new line as string arg for write
    mov     rdx, 1              ; new line string length
    mov     rax, 1              ; write
    syscall

    test    rax, rax
    jle     error               ; if write failed, go to error
    jmp     success             ; else go to success

success:
    pop     rax                 ; Get number of chars printed by print_string
    inc     rax                 ; Add new line printed by print_newline to this number
    jmp     end

error:
    pop     rax
    mov     rax, -1             ; Return EOF (alias -1) on error
    jmp     end

end:
    ret
```

Sorry if my code looks terrible, I started assembly a week ago.
I'm new to Stack Overflow and the help center told me to give a code for testing my code. So, here is a main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_puts(const char *s);

int main(void)
{
    char    *str;
    int     ret[2];

    str = strdup(".");

    write(1, "[", 1);
    ret[0] = puts(str);
    write(1, "]", 1);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    write(1, "[", 1);
    ret[1] = ft_puts(str);
    write(1, "]\n", 2);

    printf("puts return value : %d | ft_puts return value : %d\n\n", ret[0], ret[1]);
    free(str);


    str = strdup("");

    write(1, "[", 1);
    ret[0] = puts(str);
    write(1, "]", 1);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    write(1, "[", 1);
    ret[1] = ft_puts(str);
    write(1, "]\n", 2);

    printf("puts return value : %d | ft_puts return value : %d\n", ret[0], ret[1]);
    free(str);

    return (0);
}
```

And to compile and run this code :)

```
nasm -f elf64 ft_puts.s -o ft_puts.o
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o ft_puts.o -o test
./test
```

The problem seems to be in my print_newline label but I can't find it. If someone can help me ? (It's hard to get some help on assembly language around me irl)
(I don't know if should include C tag to my question too haha, so much questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems. One, the `call strlen` is allowed to clobber some registers which include `rdi` and you need that later. So, surround the `call strlen` with `push rdi` and `pop rdi` to save and restore it.

Second, you do not initialize `rdi` in the `print_newline` block. You need to set it to `1` for `stdout` just like you did in the `print_string` block.

PS: You should learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice :) The initializiation of rdi in the print_newline block was indeed the solution to my problem. (I will try a debugger one day)

Comment: Programming in asm without a debugger is a bit like driving a car without rear view mirrors. <g>